# Tor browser won't open (kali roling 2016.2)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, kali-linux

When I launch tor ('`tor`' command via the shell), the shell show me theses lines :

[image]

But, nothing happen after the "Bootstrapped 100%: Done" :/

- I restart my computer and re-tested
- I purge tor (`sudo apt-get purge tor`) and reinstall it ([with this tutorial](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/12/16/installing-tor-kali-linux/), Option #2: "Install Tor from Debian Wheezy Repository")
- I check if any another tor process running via 'ps -aux | grep tor', but no...

I don't know where is the problem..Thanks for any help !

Kali version, `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Kali 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=kali-rolling
DISTRIB_CODENAME=kali-rolling 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling" 
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling" 
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali 
VERSION="2016.2" 
VERSION_ID="2016.2" 
ID_LIKE=debian
...
```

Comment: tor isn't tor browser, it's just the daemon that provides the connectivity. to use tor browser, download it from the https://torproject.org website.

Answer (score 1):

What you see in your terminal is correct. Tor is running. The local proxy for Tor is usually set as 127.0.0.1 and the port is 9050. If you put in your SOCKS5 proxy settings in your default browser in Kali as this local IP address and port, .onion sites should load fine. You can run tor as a background process by passing the parameter `--daemon` or editing your `torrc` file (usually in `/etc/tor/torrc`) and adding `RunAsDaemon=1` because the default is `0`.